# Unity ADS ошибка при воспроизведении рекламы

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возникла проблема при попытке воспроизвести рекламу.
В консоли появляется только журнал ошибок:
Please consider upgrading to the Packman Distribution of the Unity Ads SDK. The Asset Store distribution will not longer be supported after Unity 2018.3 UnityEngine.Advertisements.Advertisement:Initialize (string,bool)
Unity ADS Скачать из PackageManager.
Вот мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class Lose_Menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject LoseMenu;
    void Start()
    {
        if(Advertisement.isSupported)
        {
            Debug.Log("Work");
            Advertisement.Initialize("4019043", false);
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
            if(other.tag == "Obstacle"){
            LoseMenu.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
            if(Advertisement.IsReady())
            {
                Debug.Log("Good");
                Advertisement.Show("video");
            }
        }
        if(other.tag == "Platform"){
            LoseMenu.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
            if(Advertisement.IsReady())
            {
                Advertisement.Show("video");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Описание работы с рекламой на unity](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
...
string gameId = "1234567";
bool testMode = true;

    void Start () {
        // Initialize the Ads service:
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testMode);
    }

    public void ShowInterstitialAd() {
        // Check if UnityAds ready before calling Show method:
        if (Advertisement.IsReady()) {
            Advertisement.Show();
        } 
        else {
            Debug.Log("Interstitial ad not ready at the moment! Please try again later!");
        }
    }
```